# nested sql queries with case statement

Tags: sql, count, subquery, case

I am trying to use the results of a subquery as a derived table for an outer query that then counts and groups the info from the subquery. This is a stretch of my SQL know-how, and I am not having luck getting the syntax right, despite looking at multiple examples online.

The subquery is:

```
SELECT rname.rn_country AS country, rname.rn_index AS id, sum(rresults.rr_sec_total) AS time 
FROM rname 
INNER JOIN rresults AS rresults ON rname.rn_index = rresults.rr_rn_index 
WHERE     rn_view = 'true'
     AND rr_date = '6/6/2012'
     AND (rr_slide = 'standard' OR rr_slide = 'water')
GROUP BY rn_index, rn_country
HAVING SUM (rresults.rr_sec_total) >= 18000
```

This results of this are:

```
country   id      time
CAN      19700    57600
USA      451294   144600.9
USA      901260   39601.8
USA      934270   109800
DEN      913601   31800
USA      915011   108720.9
```

What I then need to do is count the number of IDs where (time >= 18000 and time <= 36000) is bronze, (time >= 36000 and <= 54000) is silver, and time > than 54000 is gold, grouped  by country. So, based on the results of the above values, the end result would be:

CAN: 1 gold

DEN: 1 bronze

USA: 3 gold 1 silver

Given this, what does the full query need to be? Thanks in advance. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If a time is exactly `36000`, it will count as both bronze and silver. Is this what you mean or do you mean to have `time < 36000` for bronze? Also, what DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the counts in individual columns like so:

```
SELECT 
    a.country,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.time > 54000 THEN 1 END) AS num_gold,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.time BETWEEN 36000 AND 54000 THEN 1 END) AS num_silver,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.time BETWEEN 18000 AND 36000 THEN 1 END) AS num_bronze
FROM
(
    SELECT rname.rn_country AS country, rname.rn_index AS id, sum(rresults.rr_sec_total) AS time 
    FROM rname 
    INNER JOIN rresults AS rresults ON rname.rn_index = rresults.rr_rn_index 
    WHERE rn_view='true' AND rr_date='6/6/2012' AND (rr_slide='standard' OR rr_slide='water')
    GROUP BY rn_index, rn_country having sum(rresults.rr_sec_total) >= 18000
) a
GROUP BY a.country
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much, Zane!

Comment: @user1467223, Great! Glad to hear it works. If you found my solution to be helpful, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!